# Autocopy user selected text in MS word

Tags: c#, ms-word, copy

I'm creating a ribbon button for MS Office Word that should copy the text that is selected by user when that button is clicked.
The problem is that I couldn't find any reference on how to do this.

I have tried the SendKeys method to send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal to the word app, but without success.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy
```